# Is there a way to bind to cn=config remotely using python-ldap?

Tags: ldap, openldap, python-ldap

I'd like to bind to OpenLDAPs `cn=config` remotely so I can setup/check LDAP ACLs remotely via my script.

Binding to my root DN works really well:

```py
LOGIN_DN  = "cn=admin,dc=foo,dc=net"
l = ldap.initialize("{}:{}".format(LDAP_URL, LDAP_PORT))
l.simple_bind_s(LOGIN_DN, password)
```

If I try the same for `cn=config` ...

```py
LOGIN_DN  = "cn=config,dc=foo,dc=net"
c = ldap.initialize("{}:{}".format(LDAP_URL, LDAP_PORT))
c.simple_bind_s(LOGIN_DN, password)
```

I will get an `ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS`-Error (using the password for the admin account). Is there any way around this? I have been looking for a solution for half a day now..

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to this myself.

#### 1. Create rootaccess.ldif

Allow write access to admin user:

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: to *
    by dn="cn=admin,dc=foo,dc=net" write
    by * none
```

#### 2. Apply the Settings

Use `ldapmodify` to add that additional `olcAccess` field

```
sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f rootaccess.ldif
```